# GIF compression for CSS data URI

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I have a 3px x 3px repeated gif that I want to add as a data URI for a background image in CSS.  However, with transparency it becomes over 1000 bytes whereas with a white background it's 45 bytes.  Is there any way this image can be encoded the same size as the white background image with the transparency?  I am using Photoshop.

The image is 9px that can be represented as the below (where the black boxes are a single colour and the hyphens are transparent areas:

```
■--
--■
-■-
```

Comment: Have you tried PNG?

Comment: It depends on how you are saving them. There are various settings you can adjust which will affect the resulting size. Also, pjc50 is correct; if you are going to embed the graphics file in the stylesheet, then why not just use a PNG? I just did a test and even the base64-encoded version of the PNG is only 149 bytes.